# domain DNS zone data as JSON using cloudflare API

Tags: json, api, cloudflare, php-curl

I'm trying to get cloudflare's API to output the DNS ZONE data for one domain formatted as JSON I can get the raw data (but when I parse it through JSON decode I just get the word ARRAY.

Could anybody tell me where I've gone wrong and it's probably very obvious but I can't work it out;

```
$headers = [ 
    'X-Auth-Email: my@email.com',
    'X-Auth-Key: jfjfh09xxxxxxxxx39nfh3',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
];

$domain = "example.com"; //domain we're changing
$ZONE_ID="h4h4hxxxxxxxxxx8e3h4"; 

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/$ZONE_ID/dns_records");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    exit('Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close ($ch);

$json = json_decode($result, true);

   echo $json;
```

I'd like to stay using php cURL

Answer (score 1):

Your code is OK but you use `echo` to display an array.
Try using `var_dump()` or `print_r()`.

```
print_r($json);
```

Comment: That's got it to display something but I could do that by simply replacing $json with $result I need to get it to be formatted like JSON

Comment: Your `$result` variable should be in JSON format. `echo $result`.

Comment: $result doesn't act like JSON its formatted like JSON but I can't load it as JSON I've used the same code else where and it's fine I'm guessing it's something about how Cloudflare's API works but can't find anything to help me understand it.

Comment: What do you mean by "load it"? If you want to use the output as a feed for some JavaScript or API make sure you have no other output but the JSON formated string. You may also consider adding a header before the output: `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: I just changed my code to handle it as a PHP Array to solve it, thanks for your help, it wasn't working as cloudflare nests the information inside of another value so I just change the receiving code to `$results->results` which fixed everything.